# JavaScript - onclick image change using 'if'

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

I tried js image changing example using two different if methods.

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="s.png">
Click image
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.getAttribute('src')=='s.png')
       image.src="m.png";
    else
       image.src="s.png";

 }
</script>
```

Above method works totally fine no matter how many times clicked on the image or no matter which image is compared inside the 'if' part.

But below method which is given in w3c doesn't work as expected.

```
function changeImage(){
   var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
   if (image.src.match("s"))
   {image.src ="m.png";}
   else
    {image.src ="s.png";}
```

This second method works only at first click. And also when the image compared inside the 'if' part is swapped with other image, it doesn't work at all even at the first click. Can someone please explain me, why second 'if' method doesn't work properly while first 'if' method works finely?

Comment: Use `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` methods of DOM elements; `image.setAttribute('src', 'm.png');`

Comment: Does it make a difference in functionality if use, "image.setAttribute('src', 'm.png')" to replace "image.src="m.png"? It didn't.

Comment: You have working example below

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is that web browser automatically adds site path to your image url because you are using relative image url. So you will have 's' character in every url (because `s` letter is in site url). And every `.match('s')` will always return true.

The solution is just to find out another checking of current image.

Here is example which logs out image src, so it should help you to understand the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0yL0fwpL/4/

Html:

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage();" src="s.png">
Click image
```

Javascript:

```
changeImage = function() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

    if (image.getAttribute('src')=='s.png') {
       image.setAttribute('src', "m.png");
    } else {
       image.setAttribute('src', "s.png");
    }
 }
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0yL0fwpL/2/

Comment: I know that "if (image.getAttribute('src')=='s.png')" works finely. What I want to know which I asked in the question is, why it works finely while "if (image.src.match("s"))" doesn't.

Comment: Another example with `match` method: https://jsfiddle.net/0yL0fwpL/3/ it seems to work